# Averaging output of dstat

Tags: command-line, networking, scripting

I need to average upload and download speed using `dstat -n`. How can I add all the received and sent data sizes that appear after `dstat -n`, so that I can add them and find average upload and download speed over some period of time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one answered,I have figured it out.
Here is how to do it. Let's say we need to average it for "2 min(120 sec)". First write it to a file named stat.txt.Refresh every second fro 120 times.

```
   dstat -n 1 120 >> stat.txt
```

Add the columns of stat.txt

```
   awk -F" " '{t1=t1+$1;t2=t2+$2}END{t1=t1/120;t2=t2/120;print t1"\t"t2}' stat.txt
```

Remove stat.txt

```
   rm stat.txt
```

We can make a script too from these commands.

Answer (score 2):

You basically want `dstat` to provide you with an average over a given time (say 120 secs). This works exactly the same as `vmstat` or `ifstat`, the first argument is the `delay`, which means the given time to provide averages over. Default is 1 second.

So this should do:

```
dstat -n 120
```

or for given interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`, do:

```
dstat -n -N eth0,eth1 120
```

or for all interfaces:

```
dstat -n -f 120
```

But if you prefer some output you can post-process, it's probably more interesting to have it write out CSV data:

```
dstat -n -f -o stat.csv 120
```

Which will write out 120sec averages out to a CSV file named `stat.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that dstat is a renamed/hacked version of the [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/) commands, and those will give you the measured traffic, not bandwidth ("speed"). To get that (and that will depend on the target system's load, the path to get there, ...), use something like curl(1), which will tell you afterwards what the average speed was. Also, most home installations are asymmetric, your upload bandwidth is a fraction of the download one.

Also consider that raw bandwith isn't enough, latency is critical for interactive applications (particularly games).

Perhaps a look at the [bufferbloat](http://www.bufferbloat.net/) phenomenon is also in order.